# Rails How to include a scss file in a specific erb view?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, erb

I want to include the `assets/stylesheets/work.scss` file in `view/work/index.html.erb`

I've check this question

[How to include a css or javascript in an erb that is outside the layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480288/how-to-include-a-css-or-javascript-in-an-erb-that-is-outside-the-layout)

and add this in `layout/application.html.erb`

```
<head>
...
<%= yield(:header) if content_for? :header%>
</head>
```

Then, add this in `index.html.erb`

```
<% content_for :header do -%>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'work' %>
<% end -%>
```

However, it threw this error
[image]

I was doing this in `development` mode instead of `production`, why I need `precompile`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are including it independently, and not including it in your `application.css`. The default for the asset pipeline is to compile `applicaiton.css/application.js` and anything that is included in those files.

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require c3
 *= require purecss
 *= require_self
 *= require pure_css_reset
 */
```

If you want it to be seperate and not compiled into the one monolithic file, being called from your `stylesheet_link_tag`, you have to manually add it to the precompile array.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets is a good reference.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it.

Comment: Yeah, if I add asset pipeline, it can work well. Thanks.