# Rails 5: CSS will not link to html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm new to rails and trying to link main.css.scss to index.html.erb file in views/main.

My css file is located in app/assets/stylesheets. This is default, I did not change anything.

---

So in my index.html.erb file I added the following:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "main" %>
```

This throwed an error which advised me to include ".css" at the end of "main". I added ".css" and ".css.scss" to the end of main. The main page loads, but without the css file.

What is the correct way to link css in rails 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the api docs [here.](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/stylesheet_link_tag) It will help you to understand how you can link css in rails.

Also take a look at [Samuel's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/480410/4614833) answer. He explained it really well.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple. If you don't want to use default `application.css` and `application.js`, then create new files, like in your case `main`:

```
app/assets/stylesheets/main.scss
app/assets/javascripts/main.js
```

Then in your layout include those files:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Foobar</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'main', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'main', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
```

And add those files to `assets.rb`:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( main.scss main.js)
```

And restart the server.